# How to show install app page of Google Play within bottom sheet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-play

I've tried all the ways listed in [Linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html#UriSummary)

like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
    "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

But they all show the install app page in an activity with full view.

Is there any way to show install app page within bottom sheet like this:
[image]

Comment: You can check my findings here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999978/7454155