# How to open Google Play Install app dialog similar to Youtube ad cliick

Tags: android, google-play, ads

I am looking forward to opening a Google play dialog as you see on YouTube when you click on any app install ads. I already tried the steps from this link to open the play store from my Android app https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play, but these steps open the play store app instead of in-app dialog like shown in the below screenshot. I already checked StackOverflow and there were a couple of similar questions asked but they are quite older so asking it again.

[image]

Comment: You can bottom sheet for this purpose and then have a Webview in it, where you can open play store

Comment: That will be a hack. But this doesn't look like a bottom sheet with WebView. Also if you open a play store in a web view it will show a button "open play store app".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all those wondering how is it possible to show this. TLDR you can't without support from Google.

The popup comes when you add extra param **enifd** with the app link to play store

For ex. intent://details?id=com.aranoah.healthkart.plus&inline=true&**enifd=AMO2QMb52SseLfA21upm-hHtBTi4ekj6AaHc14FJPukdGkE3WL5_pWrxfL3m3lSmhAHhXZpLALwiPh6aTUOdtKjgAaWMet8NBtlmJkrfA44-9oau3Lyjud9gvkBQu2goXdqxts7gWvrCky_gBJIa-9RxYio2DHOc0wg5o2PbRbhxcmZtgMpIePs&gclid=Cj0KCQiAsqOMBhDFARIsAFBTN3ejj8e-8jcA0bbPoIQipj3502K_-o-UEO44kIO4iUUHBvHOVPrg4aIaApfJEALw_wcB&referrer=gclid%3DCj0KCQiAsqOMBhDFARIsAFBTN3ejj8e-8jcA0bbPoIQipj3502K_-o-UEO44kIO4iUUHBvHOVPrg4aIaApfJEALw_wcB&gref=EkUKPQoJCICyo4wGEMUBEiwAUFM3d6OPx77yNwDRts-ghCKmPfnTYr_6j5QQ7jiQg7iJRQcG8c5U-uDhohoCl8kQAvD_BwEYgdnLvgMiCBgFIAEwATgH**#Intent;scheme=market;package=com.android.vending;end;

This enifd param contains gpId based some configuration in encrypted manner if you add this to applink and then try to fire applink from any of your app then you will see the bottomsheet. But if you remove this param it will again open the play store app.

Though the link is copied from Chrome so I am not aware what exactly is being passed under enifd param. Check with Google if you want to find out.

Comment: How can I get the ink of app that promoted then edit it ?

Comment: @MML even though you can get this URL you cannot modify it, as the enifId is unique per app and it's encrypted so you can't change it.

Comment: where can i get this url?

Comment: Where to get the enifd ?

Comment: You cannot unless you have partnership with google