# Show instant installation pop up from google play store on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, deep-linking, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have published my flutter app on google play store and want to share it through facebook posts. I want a deep link whenever it is clicked, it opens a something like popup which shows play store as in the picture below. I posted my google play store link of my app on facebook but it just redirects me to a page with black app bar and blank page NOT PLAY STORE.
It is the sample link which I clicked on it from facebook android app and it opens google play store like this.
[image: sample working picture.]

Comment: you can see my findings here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999978/7454155

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it is a facebook issue because it works fine for other devices and gets stuck in some devices.the only thing it needs is to use the package or plugin and setup it on facebook by mentioning your mainActivity and your package name and providing the right hash key provided by sha1 of google play store.