# I want to show a dialog for downloading an app within my app, as Facebook shows for the Messenger app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Consider: thanks in advance

```
val appPackageName = "com.facebook.orca"
val launchIntent: Intent? =
    packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.orca")
try {
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        // We found the activity now start the activity
        //  launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(launchIntent)
    }
    else {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = Uri.parse(
                "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")
            setPackage("com.android.vending")
        }
        startActivity(intent)
        // startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.facebook.orca")))
    }
} catch (ex: Exception) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = Uri.parse(
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")
        setPackage("com.android.vending")
    }
    startActivity(intent)
    // startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.facebook.orca[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q1Xh.png)")))
}
```

I just want to add an option in my app to allow downloading  app from play store. As shown in the image.

[image: As shown in the image]

Comment: So what is you question?

Comment: I want to show download option like facebook shows for  Messenger app.

Comment: This is not a question. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi5JS.png

check this image how can i show dialog like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Google Play Install app dialog similar to Youtube ad cliick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709394/how-to-open-google-play-install-app-dialog-similar-to-youtube-ad-cliick)

Comment: yes exactly like this

Comment: can you tell me how to create that type of link?

Comment: The post has answered that. The answer is you can't, unless you become a Google partner.