# how to show the google play store inside the my own app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, ads

I am fascinating how XRecorder android app implement showing the google play store page in the app without leaving its own app. I really want to how how this is implemented.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Google Play Install app dialog similar to Youtube ad cliick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709394/how-to-open-google-play-install-app-dialog-similar-to-youtube-ad-cliick)