# How to get permission to open google play install modal

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, ads

I'm looking to open the google play install modal instead of opening up google play store app like this for my own app:

[image]

However, [looking online](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999978/14344178), it seems that you need permission from google to do so for your app?

I'm wondering if anybody has any luck doing so in getting permission from google and the steps needed to do so.

Thanks in advance!